grep condition to grab certain text only
so i am trying to grab certain output from grep command
here is the command i am trying
nslookup -type=TXT "_dmarc.$domain" | grep -Eo '\s*reject|\s*quarantine|\s*none|\s*no answer' || echo "no answer"

its working pretty good for normal domains.
the trouble starts when the dmarc record has this output
v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=none; adkim=s; aspf=s; rua=mailto:dmarc@domain.com; ruf=mailto:dmarc@domain.com

i dont know much about grep but i tired using match case but now the output is
root@main-room:~/spfscript/newupdate# nslookup -type=TXT "_dmarc.domain.com" | grep -Eo '\s*reject|\s*quarantine|\s*none|\s*no answer' || echo "no answer"
reject
none
root@main-room:~/spfscript/newupdate# 

because p=reject and sp=none i am not able to control the grep to only present me with "p=" policy
please help me in this
let me know what i can do more.
i tried adding space but i am not sure if i am doing it correctly.

There you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

It's not clear what's your goal. Do you want to exclude '=reject' ? Sometrhing like -Eo '\s+reject|\s*quarantine|\s*none|\s*no answer' ?

Please add your expected output so we don;t have to guess at what it might be and have something we can copy/paste as-is to test a potential solution with.

so my goal is to extract the policies only.
and there are 2 policies. one is domain policy and other is subdomain policy. represented as p and sp.
so currently i only wanna extract p="whatever the policy"

or taking into account ABNF of DMARC spec, it could be smth like nslookup -type=TXT "_dmarc.stackoverflow.com" | sed -nr 's/.*"v\s*=\s*DMARC1\s*;\s*p\s*=\s*(none|quarantine|reject)("|\s*;.*").*/\1/p'

You need to match p= before the words you're looking for, and there must be a space or ; before p so it won't match sp=.
grep -Eo '[\s;]p\s*=\s*(reject|quarantine|none|no answer)'

You can remove everything up to p= from the beginning after assigning the variable.
If you're using GNU grep, you can use PCRE. Then p= can be a lookbehind and you won't have to remove it after, and you can use \b to match a word boundary.
grep -Po '(?<=\bp=)(reject|quarantine|none|no answer)'


upvoted too, btw the dmarc-sep is defined as *WSP %x3b *WSP and dmarc-req as "p" *WSP "=" *WSP, i.e. there are possible extra whitespaces (around "=") or their absense (before "p")

@yvs2014 I've added that in to my first solution. But most regexp engines don't allow variable-length lookbehinds, so not the second solution.

@Barmar whitespace before "p" is not mandatory too according to DMARC spec

@yvs2014 That makes things trickier when \b isn't available. I've added a match for ; there, but that will be included in the match and will need to be stripped off. Do I need to match ^, or will it always start with v=DMARC<version>;?

\s*;\s* is mandatory before "p" according
dmarc-version dmarc-sep [dmarc-request] [dmarc-sep dmarc-srequest] .... ABNF taken from https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7489 So that could be ;p= or ; p =  etc. And endings could be tricky because of for example "p=nonenotnone" could be false positive. Sed version of regexp is above in comments, unless I've made a mistake somewhere there.

Consider a starting point where you populate an array (t2v[] below) indexed by tags like p with their associated values, e.g.:
$ awk -F'[=; ]+' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) t2v[$i]=$(i+1); print t2v["p"]}' file
reject


$ awk -F'[=; ]+' '{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) t2v[$i]=$(i+1)
    for (tag in t2v) print tag "=" t2v[tag]
}' file
v=DMARC1
rua=mailto:dmarc@domain.com
adkim=s
sp=none
p=reject
ruf=mailto:dmarc@domain.com
aspf=s

That would give you a lot more control over the values you want to find, compare, reassign, reorder or do anything else with, e.g.:
awk -F'[=; ]+' '
    { for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) t2v[$i]=$(i+1) }
    t2v["p"] ~ /^(reject|quarantine|none|no answer)$/ { print t2v["p"]; f=1 }
    END { if (!f) { print "no answer"; exit 1 } }
' file
reject


awk -F'[=; ]+' -v OFS=';' '
    { for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) t2v[$i]=$(i+1) }
    (t2v["p"] ~ /^(reject|quarantine|none|no answer)$/) &&
    (t2v["sp"] == "none") &&
    (t2v["rua"] == t2v["ruf"]) {
        print t2v["rua"], t2v["v"], t2v["aspf"]
        f=1
    }
    END { if (!f) { print "no answer"; exit 1 } }
' file
mailto:dmarc@domain.com;DMARC1;s

